# "Recent reviews" links to "Review Stats

Tags: feature-request, review, review-stats

For every review queue on the [main review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), there's a **recent reviews »** link under the avatars of the five most recent reviewers.

However, if you click **recent reviews »**, it leads you to e.g., [`/review/close/stats`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), which shows the top reviewers of today and all time, but not even a hint about recent reviews.

For users with [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), it would suffice to link to [`/review/close/history`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history). For users with less than 10k reputation, that's only slightly better, since they can only see their own reviews.

I propose to change the link to one of the following:

1. [top reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)
2. [recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) for users with 10k reputation or more and [my recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) for the others
3. [top reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) | [(my) recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history)

Option 3 is my personal favorite (it's not like there isn't enough space for both).

Comment: Why not just two links appropriately named "stats" and "history" to match the tabs?

Comment: I suppose the intention was to explain beforehand what the user is going to see and I tried to keep it that way, but that would work too.

Comment: It's a shame that this issue is still not fixed yet in April 2019.

Answer (score 10):

The recent reviews link should link to... recent reviews.

The current set-up is just confusing<sup>1</sup>; I click on the link expecting to go and see the recent reviews (normally when I want to find a specific review). I then get shunted sideways to the stats page and have to click a second time in order to get to what I was originally promised.

> [image]

... should send you...

> [image]

For users with less than 10k this would show them their recent reviews in that queue, for users with more than 10k this would show them everyone's.

That would be my preferred option at any rate. If it's not agreeable could the link be renamed to stats so that it at least takes you where you'd expect.

For double-plus bonus points do as animuson suggests in the comments and have three links, that link to all three pages:

> [image]

<sub>1. 6 months later, still making the same mistake.</sub>

Comment: Coming up on 7 months :)

Comment: I'm a quick learner @Cole.