# Redundancy in the new review page — "Stats" and "Recent reviews" both point to the same page

Tags: feature-request, review, design

The review page recently received two new buttons for each review queue called "Stats" and "History", placed under the name of each review queue.

> [image: Screenshot of part of the review queues on Literature SE, showing the new "Stats" and "History" links, as well as the old "Recent reviews" link]

For instance, on Literature SE, the link on "Stats" points to https://literature.stackexchange.com/review/review/close/stats and similarly for the other review queues and on other sites, including Meta sites.

This makes the old link to "Recent reviews" under the identicons of recent reviewers redundant, since it points to the same page as the "Stats" link. The labelling is also [confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164972/313042) — does "Recent reviews" refer to *your* recent reviews, aka "History", or *overall* recent reviews, aka "Stats"? It turns out to be the former, but I think it might be better to do away with the "Recent reviews" link completely, since the two new links are doing a good job.

---

**Feature request:** Remove the old link to the stats page titled "Recent reviews" near the user identicons in the review queues.